# Select element two level up in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<p class="align-with-btn">
  <a class="with-icon add-new-line" id="add-line" href="#add-new-line">
    <i class="icon-add-inv"></i>Add Reference
 </a>
</p>
<div class="row update-button">
  <div class="span4">
   <button class="submitAesReference loadRef btn" id="submitReference">
      <i class="icon-submit"></i>Submit  Reference
   </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here i want to select hide link with class name **"add-new-line"** when i click on the button below

i tried

```
var button = $(this);
button.closest('.span4').parent().closest('.add-new-line').hide();
```

but its not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest` only iterates through the parents of the element but `.add-new-line` isn't a parent of `.row`. 
So you'll have to do something like

`button.closest('.row').prev().find('.add-new-line')`.

Or you wrap your `p.align-with-btn`and `div.row` into another element, for example `div.wrapper`. then you could do:

`button.closest('.wrapper').find('.add-new-line')`

That way you don't have to need to use `.prev()` which can break easily, if you introduce new elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the previous element of current button's parent `.row` element

```
button.closest('.row').prev().find('.add-new-line').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that your `.add-new-line` element also has an ID. Why not just use that?

```
$('#add-line').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

First select the row parent of the button and then find its siblings (p) and then find the a tag inside the p tag.

$('button').parents('.row').siblings('p').find('a.add-new-line').hide();

hope this helps.